# set variable different time interval in set interval

Tags: javascript, timeout, setinterval

i have a function named checkInactivity i want to execute this function in variable time interval . i am fetching the time interval getInactiveTimePeriod and is tored in variable timeInMilliseconds. this varibale (timeInMilliseconds) holds different timings in each time its a value selected from database. i want to run the function checkInactivity with this variable time time interval ie depends on the value of timeInMilliseconds.
Please help me to solve this. Thank you in advance.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    setInactiveMode();
    setInactiveTimePeriod();
    getInactiveTimePeriod();
 } , 100000);

 var applicationsopend = [];
 var applicationTabId = {};
 var timeInseconds;

 function getInactiveTimePeriod() {
    chrome.storage.local.get("user_inactive_time", function (obj) {
        timeInMinuts = obj.user_inactive_time;
        timeInMilliseconds = timeInMinuts *(60000);
        setTimeout(() => { 
            checkInactivity();
        }, timeInMilliseconds);

    });
 }

// getInactiveTimePeriod();

 function checkInactivity() {
    chrome.storage.local.get("user_inactive_mode", function (obj) {
        inactiveStatusMode = obj.user_inactive_mode;
        if(inactiveStatusMode == 'true') {
            var timeInseconds = timeInMilliseconds / 1000;
            chrome.idle.queryState(timeInseconds, function (state) {
                if (state === "active") {
                    chrome.storage.local.get( "appList", function (obj) {
                        appList = obj.appList.split(",");
                        var queryInfo = {
                            // active: false,
                        currentWindow: false
                        };
                        chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function (tabs) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                                var taburl = tabs[i]['url'];
                                currentApp = findApp(taburl);
                                currentHashUrl = CryptoJS.SHA1(currentApp).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
                                if($.inArray(currentHashUrl, appList) != -1 && currentApp != 'onionid' ) {
                                    var tabid = tabs[i]['id'];
                                    currentApp = findApp(taburl);
                                    applicationTabId[currentApp] = tabid;
                                }
                            }
                            //console.log(applicationTabId);
                            getapplicationlogouturl(applicationTabId);
                        });
                    }); 
                }
            });  
        }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've retrieved the time you want to use for interval, use `setInterval()` to call the function indefinately every given milliseconds:

```js
function getInactiveTimePeriod() {
    chrome.storage.local.get("user_inactive_time", function (obj) {
        let timeInMinutes = obj.user_inactive_time;
        let timeInMilliseconds = timeInMinutes * (60000);
        setInterval(() => {
            checkInactivity();
        }, timeInMilliseconds);
    });
}
```

Note that if you want to use this value in some other place, it should be declared in the higher scope:

```js
// global declaration
var timeInMilliseconds;

function getInactiveTimePeriod() {
    chrome.storage.local.get("user_inactive_time", function (obj) {
        let timeInMinutes = obj.user_inactive_time;
        timeInMilliseconds = timeInMinutes * (60000); // setting the globally declared variable
        setInterval(() => {
            checkInactivity();
        }, timeInMilliseconds);
    });
}

function checkInactivity() {
    var timeInseconds = timeInMilliseconds / 1000; // use the globally declared variable

    // ...
}
```

Comment: getInactiveTimePeriod() function is working in 100000ms checkInactivity is also working in this interval regardless of timeInMilliseconds.

i have added   console.log('jkdfkjhf' + time); to check the status and working as jkdfkjhf15:44:0 next jkdfkjhf15:45:40 ie in 100000ms

Comment: are you sure that you retrieve the correct value from ```chrome.storage```? If you do a ```console.log(obj)``` in ```getInactiveTimePeriod``` what is the output you get?

Comment: iam getting it as 180000

Comment: If you get ```180000``` in ```obj```, you should use it as is to set ```timeInMinutes```, not ```obj.user_inactive_time```.